# How do I loop through two sections as one set

Tags: entries, loop

I'm trying to loop through two separate channels, but combined together. And then just check which channel the entry belongs to in the loop to display it correctly. This is how I had it done in EE, but I can't seem to find a way with Craft.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="press|in-the-press" orderby="date" dynamic="no" limit="10"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Craft docs, the [section parameter](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#section) takes a "section handle, an array of section handles, or a SectionModel object". So this should work:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section(['press', 'in-the-press']).limit(10) %}

{% for entry in entries %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: got it, i was forgetting the brackets. thanks :)